# Get timestamp of first day of the same month from UNIX timestamp without any conversions to local time

Tags: c++, time

Suppose that I have UNIX timestamp like this

```
1252301772
```

and I need to convert it to another timestamp representing the first day of the same month (without any conversions to the local time or something like this). Example:

```
1252301772 -> 07 Sep 2009 05:36:12 GMT
x -> 01 Sep 2009 00:00:00 GMT
```

Comment: That wouldn't be possible, since the timestamp alone without the time zone doesn't tell you what month it is.

Comment: @gnasher729 What do you mean? Unix timestamp is in UTC.

Comment: @admdrew Yep, but I need to convert **any** UNIX timestamp to the first day of the month that it's represent, how ca I achieve it without any time zones, etc?

Comment: @gnasher729 based on the wording of the question I'd assume they want to assume UTC. Wouldn't hurt to clarify though.

Comment: @Mark Ransom Yep, I mean UTC

Comment: A  UTC timestamp is different days and 1/30ish of the time different months depending on where you're asking about.

Comment: @JonathanWakely When discussing "days", there is no such thing as universal time.  It's not possible to extract a day from any UTC timestamp without specifying local midnight's relation to UTC.  The fact that in about 4% of the world that offset is zero doesn't justify pretending it's zero everywhere else, unless you really don't care whether you can even get the month right anyway -- in which case why bother asking?

Comment: @jthill, _"It's not possible to extract a day from any UTC timestamp without specifying local midnight's relation to UTC."_ Isn't that what `gmtime` does, without specifying anything about the local time? It's defined to give you the broken-down time in UTC, not UTC+0 (despite the name implying GMT)

Comment: @JonathanWakely I'm afraid I'm missing the point here, I can't see any difference between utc and a time zero hours and zero minutes different from utc.

Comment: @jthill, my point is just that if "there's no such thing" and "it's not possible" then what is `gmtime` doing?

Comment: @JonathanWakely It's giving the correct answer for that 4%ish of the world whose local midnight equals UTC midnight.  The act of associating a day/month/year to a seconds-since-epoch value is all by itself a conversion to local time, whether or not you actually add a zero  offset or any other to the seconds-since-epoch value first.

Comment: @jthill then you should report a defect against the C standard, which claims `gmtime` gives you a time expressed in UTC, not a time expressed in the local time that coincides with it. And fix [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) which says "UTC divides time into days, hours, minutes and seconds. Days are conventionally identified using the Gregorian calendar, but Julian day numbers can also be used. Each day contains 24 hours and each hour contains 60 minutes."

Comment: @JonathanWakely I don't think they really expected anyone to insist that any timestamp value denotes the same day everywhere, or that an answer that's valid only in timezones that match utc somehow isn't local time. (edit: and Wikipedia also mentions that it's discussing "The UTC time zone".)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67160/discussion-between-jonathan-wakely-and-jthill).

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <time.h>

time_t first_of_the_month(time_t t)
{
  struct tm tmt;
  if (!gmtime_r(&t, &tmt))
    return -1;
  tmt.tm_sec = 0;
  tmt.tm_min = 0;
  tmt.tm_hour = 0;
  tmt.tm_mday = 1;
  tmt.tm_isdst = -1;
  return timegm(&tmt);
}
```

This uses the non-standard `timegm` function (thanks to Jeremy Friesner for pointing that out). If that function isn't available on your platform you can use `mktime` but that depends on the local timezone, so you would need to adjust the program's timezone (by setting `TZ` in the environment and calling tzset) before and after calling `mktime`, which is not thread-safe because it alters global program state.

Comment: Is there any analogue of `mktime` function then?

Comment: No, unfortunately I think you need to fart about with `tzset`

Comment: Even using any third-party libraries?

Comment: timegm() might be the mktime()-alternative you guys are looking for.